# Implementing Google Analytics Event Tracking using C# for a button

Tags: javascript, c#, google-analytics

I'm very new to this, so expect me to not know a lot of the basics. I'm working off of what someone else coded.

I want to add this snippet of code: (it basically sends an event to google analytics)

`ga('send', 'event', 'Registeration Form', 'Filled', 'Campaign');`

When this button is clicked:

```html
<!----- Submit and Reset ------->
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="req1"  CausesValidation="true" 
       OnClick="BtnSubmit_OnClick" ID="BtnSubmit"  class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success"/>
</div>
```

I have this on my other page:

```cs
protected void BtnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SendMail();
        Clear();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Where do I put my code that sends an event?
I tried putting it between the div, it didn't work.
I tried creating a function on my main page:

```html
<!-- Event Tracking for Submit Button -->
<script>
   function formButton() {
       ga('send', 'event', 'Registeration Form', 'Filled', 'Campaign');
   }
</script>
```

and running this code on the other page:

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "text", formButton(), true);`

It still didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would add the code within the onclick  function you have defined as below. This is because you have defined the function and assigned it to onclick, google analytics needs something to prompt the loading of the script, in this case the onclick event

`protected void BtnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Registeration Form', 'Filled', 'Campaign');
        SendMail();
        Clear();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}`